# Android with Google Cloud Storage got Invalid Credentials

Tags: android, google-api-java-client, google-cloud-storage

I want to use Google Storage from my android device. I enable google storage service and google storage json api. I enable the billing too.

I got my SHA1 fingerprint from the following command line :

```
keytool -list -v -keystore  ~/.android/debug.keystore
```

I set the "SHA1 key;com.mydomain" in the api console and I got my Simple API.

I am trying to get the content of the bucket but I am stuck with the following error:

```
 com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
    {
    "code" : 401,
    "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "location" : "Authorization",
    "locationType" : "header",
    "message" : "Invalid Credentials",
    "reason" : "authError"
    } ],
    "message" : "Invalid Credentials"
    }
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:111)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:38)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:312)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1042)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
    at com.zenittude.image.importer.GoogleCloudStorageImageImporter.getBucket(GoogleCloudStorageImageImporter.java:183)
    at com.zenittude.image.importer.GoogleCloudStorageImageImporter.access$300(GoogleCloudStorageImageImporter.java:61)
    at com.zenittude.image.importer.GoogleCloudStorageImageImporter$BucketTask.doInBackground(GoogleCloudStorageImageImporter.java:212)
    at com.zenittude.image.importer.GoogleCloudStorageImageImporter$BucketTask.doInBackground(GoogleCloudStorageImageImporter.java:194)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

This is my class :

```
    @EBean
public class GoogleCloudStorageImageImporter implements IImageImporter {

    public static final String TAG = "GoogleCloudStorageImageImporter";

    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "MyCompany-MyApp/1.0";

    private final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory();

    private HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();


    private GoogleCloudSettings settings;


    private Storage storage;

    @RootContext
    Activity activity;

    @RootContext
    Context context;


    @Bean(DefaultImageManager.class)
    IImageManager imageManager;

    @Bean(OrmliteRepositoryManager.class)
    ILocalRepository repository;

    Account account;

    GoogleAccountCredential credential;




    private void readSettings() {
        settings = GoogleCloudSettings.load(JSON_FACTORY,
                                            GoogleCloudSettings.class.getResourceAsStream("/foo_settings.json"));

        settings.setBucket("client-" + MainApplication.getBusinessId());

    }

    private Storage getStorageService() {

        StorageRequestInitializer storageRequestInitializer = new StorageRequestInitializer(ClientCredentials.API_KEY);

        return new Storage.Builder(transport,
                                    JSON_FACTORY,
                                    credential)
                                    .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                                    .setStorageRequestInitializer(storageRequestInitializer)
                                    .build();
    }


    public void doImport() {

        try {
            // settings
            readSettings();

            if( account == null) {
                GoogleAccountManager googleAccountManager = new GoogleAccountManager(activity);
                Account[] accounts = googleAccountManager.getAccountManager().getAccountsByType(GoogleAuthUtil.GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_TYPE);
                account = accounts[2];
            }


            new BucketTask().execute(account);

        } catch (Throwable t) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error while trying to import images from server",  t);
        }
    }

    private Bucket getBucket() {

        Log.i("Getting bucket " + settings.getBucket() + " metadata");
        Bucket bucket = null;
        try {
            Storage.Buckets.Get getBucket = storage.buckets().get(settings.getBucket());
            getBucket.setPrettyPrint(true);
            bucket = getBucket.execute();
            Log.i(bucket.toPrettyString());
        } catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException e) {
            activity.startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), StartupActivity.REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "unable to get the bucket", e);
        }
        return bucket;

    }

    private class BucketTask extends AsyncTask<Account, Void, Bucket> {
        @Override
        protected Bucket doInBackground(Account... params) {



            try {

                if(credential == null) {
                    Account account = params[0];
                    credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(activity, Collections.singleton(StorageScopes.DEVSTORAGE_READ_ONLY));
                    credential.setSelectedAccountName(account.name);
                }

                if( storage == null && credential != null) {
                    storage = getStorageService();
                }

                return getBucket();


        } catch (Throwable t) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error while trying to import images from server", t);
            }
            return null;
        }

         @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bucket result) {
            //Do something with result
            if (result != null)
                result.getId();
        }
    }
}
```

I followed the [Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/auth/android) sample.

Any advice ?

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely understand, but are you sure that the third result from getAccountsByType() is always going to be the account with appropriate permissions to access the Cloud Storage API?

Comment: Hi Brandron, the code is executed on my device and I have 3 accounts :) It's only set for sample purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the issue.

Don't use the **Simple API Access** coming from the API console but you have to setup the **Client ID for installed applications** (see the Drive SDK link above)

So instead of :

```
private Storage getStorageService() {

        StorageRequestInitializer storageRequestInitializer = new StorageRequestInitializer(ClientCredentials.API_KEY);

        return new Storage.Builder(transport,
                                    JSON_FACTORY,
                                    credential)
                                    .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                                    .setStorageRequestInitializer(storageRequestInitializer)
                                    .build();
    }
```

you should use it like this:

```
private Storage getStorageService() {

        return new Storage.Builder(transport,
                                    JSON_FACTORY,
                                    credential)
                                    .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                                    .build();
    }
```

Hope that help !

Comment: Glad you figured out the answer! Please accept your answer so others can see that there is an answer.

Comment: Can you post a working snippet of how you followed this API to upload a file on Android. I am not able to find any answer on stackoverflow or elsewhere in the Internet. Thx